# Compose Fragment crashes application when using Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently facing a really weird issue in Jetpack Compose. I am using the Navigation Component library (hosting Fragments in a NavHostFragment). Some newer Fragments are already using Compose, but I get this crash on a rare occasion. Mostly when navigating using the Navigation Drawer to the settings page and clicking back on an item in the Bottom Navigation View. I am currently using Jetpack Compose alpha-12 and Navigation 2.3.0.

(does not crash when using normal ViewBinding)

https://youtu.be/__pdZmApEfE

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class StatisticsFragment : Fragment() {

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
      setContent {
        TemporyTheme {
          Text("Hello Compose!")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...>

    <RelativeLayout
        ...>

        <RelativeLayout
            ...>

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                ... />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- NavHost -->
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main"
            ... />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        .../>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setLayoutDirection(AndroidComposeView.kt:797)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(AndroidComposeView.kt:724)
        at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:20272)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:7765)
        at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:6781)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:6112)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:689)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:685)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.<init>(AndroidComposeView.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrapperKt.setContent(Wrapper.kt:123)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.kt:183)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.kt:215)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5278)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.addView(FragmentContainerView.java:290)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.addViewToContainer(FragmentStateManager.java:830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:520)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2177)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2094)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: unfortunately not, I am currently sticking with view binding and only use compose in entirely different parts of the app. hopefully this is a bug that gets fixed in a later release.

Comment: @AndréRamon I filed a bug for something similar to this. You might want to star it? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181463117

Comment: I will retry it with beta-02..

Comment: Seems to be fixed with beta 06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error went away with beta 06 of compose